# прокси для сервера на комьютере

Tags: сеть

В сетях не разбираюсь, прошу помочь. 
Есть vps, он очень слабый.Хочу использовать его как прокси со своего компьютера

Подскажите как пробросить порт.

мой компьютер[8080]->server->internet[8080]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я использовал ngrok
есть проброс http и https